# How to gray out few option items in SelectItem in smartgwt?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am trying to disable few option items in SelectItem in smartgwt but have not been able to find a suitable API. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Use an optionDataSource to provide the values for the SelectItem.  You can then set the ListGridRecords disabled using the ListGrid.recordEnabledProperty, or if you them just greyed out but not disabled, use SelectItem.setPickListFields() to install formatting and styling overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me, why do you want to do so? If you want some options not to be selected, then don't include them in selectItem.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop down a grid, and disable in that.